# How can i restart application from main.lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

i am loading data from server and then in the next scene i am displaying that data in a list. But when i upload some new data in that case i need to restart my app from main.lua to show the new posts to users. I just have tried the following code:

```
storyboard.gotoScene("main","fromRight");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload/restart your scene using this:

```
storyboard.reloadScene()
```

This [Link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/reloadScene.html) can probably help you.

Comment: But my question is something i want to load from main.lua so, how is this possible to restart app from main.lua from scene01,scene02 or any other scene

Comment: @Nomi Check If your main scene name Is main, If that didn't work, Create a new scene and call it something like lobby, on main start the lobby and that allows you to move scenes easily from other scenes.

Comment: Yea that what i can do is but i cannot come from main.lua :/

Comment: @Nomi Can you add codes you made to the topic? This way I probably can get what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I think the answer of my question is in making a new scene after main.lua that has the that functionality that i have written in main.lua. :)

Comment: @Nomi Yep, That's what I said.